# how can i sort data by rows? [MYSQL]

Tags: mysql

my database

| id | title | create_by |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 2 |
| 2 | bbb | 1 |
| 3 | ccc | 3 |
| 4 | ddd | 2 |
| 5 | eee | 2 |
| 6 | fff | 3 |

what i want. sort by row that have same most value.

| id | title | create_by |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 2 |
| 4 | ddd | 2 |
| 5 | eee | 2 |
| 3 | ccc | 3 |
| 6 | fff | 3 |
| 2 | bbb | 1 |

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT id,
                     title,
                     create_by,
                     COUNT(create_by) OVER (PARTITION BY create_by) cnt
              FROM src_table )
SELECT id,
       title,
       create_by
FROM cte
ORDER BY cnt, id;
```

Comment: not work 'cnt' give me total of row in table (from ex. result  'cnt' is 6 every row)

Comment: @AnusornKongthong Inaccuracy, fixed.

Comment: @Akina: note that there is no need for a CTE. Window functions are allowed in the `ORDER BY` clause.